# Unsupported Argument Error for 'multi_az_with_standby_enabled' in AWS OpenSearch Terraform Configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, opensearch

I am working with AWS OpenSearch using Terraform and encountered an error when trying to enable the `multi_az_with_standby_enabled` setting. My Terraform configuration includes this line:

```
resource "aws_opensearch_domain" "main" {
  ...
  multi_az_with_standby_enabled = true
  ...
}
```

However, when I apply the configuration, I get the following error:

```
Error: Unsupported argument
on opensearch/main.tf line 73, in resource "aws_opensearch_domain" "main":
  multi_az_with_standby_enabled = true

An argument named "multi_az_with_standby_enabled" is not expected here.
```

I am confused because this configuration option is present in the codebase [2] but seems to be missing from the official AWS Terraform provider documentation [1]

Is `multi_az_with_standby_enabled` a valid argument for an OpenSearch domain in Terraform? If so, why might it be causing an error, and how can I resolve this issue? If it's not a valid argument, why is it present in the code?

I appreciate any insights or guidance on this matter.

[1] https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/5.34.0/docs/resources/opensearch_domain#cluster_config

[2] https://github.com/mikekinlock/terraform-provider-aws/commit/12ce033efc52e5c7b9db3853ab3b7f9229bb5351

Updated link:

[2] https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/blob/main/internal/service/opensearch/domain.go#L274

Answer (score 2):

The provider code you linked against is a fork of the official provider, and therefore would be inconsistent with the official documentation you linked against. However, according to the code the issue here with your usage is that the argument must be nested within a `cluster_config` block:

```
resource "aws_opensearch_domain" "main" {
  ...
  cluster_config {
    multi_az_with_standby_enabled = true
  }
  ...
}
```

That usage would correct the issue if you are using the forked provider, but would still be an unsupported argument with the official provider.

With the corrected link against the official provider there are a couple more notes here. The first is that `terraform-plugin-docs` should generate documentation against the populated attribute schema. The second is that the AWS provider (I believe) normally generates documentation in CI against a release. These both contribute to a suspicion about the lack of documentation around the parameter, and that it is probably incomplete.

All that being said: based on the code and the usage of the SDKv2 in the resource (since direct support of establishing attributes as blocks did not exist previous to the plugin framework module) the code snippet in this answer would be correct usage if it is possible.

Comment: I tried inside `cluster_config` as well. And here is the link from offcial harshicorp code base. https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/blob/main/internal/service/opensearch/domain.go#L274

Comment: Which provider version are you using?

Comment: @Sarangan Ok updating information against your corrected link.

Comment: To address this issue in terraform-provider-aws, a PR has been raised. You can view it [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/pull/35628#pullrequestreview-1862360114).